# Why are my custom controls not always receiving MouseEnter events?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

Alright, I'm fairly new to WPF and I ran into a very strange problem. The relevant section of my XAML defines a Border around a ScrollViewer around a StackPanel which is populated using an ItemsControl that is then databound to a CollectionViewSource which in turn wraps a standard ObservableCollection. The ItemsControl defines a DataTemplate that contains only one tag: a custom control I've made called a StackElement. I'm handling three events from this control — MouseEnter, MouseLeave, and PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp. These events can fire, but do so unreliably.

For example, after some new StackElements are added, the MouseEnter event generally doesn't fire on the *first* StackElement until I've moused over a few others. Once a MouseOver manages to fire once, it continues to fire correctly on that StackElement from there on out.

However, the first time mousing over a StackElement doesn't always fail. If I approach the StackElements from *beneath* and try the last one first, it will always fire. When I do this, sometimes the first one will work, but the second one won't fire. Once, both of them did manage to operate correctly, but it happens infrequently.

I'm not multithreading anything, none of my parent controls handle events of their own, all event handlers consist only of a WriteLine() statement for debugging purposes, and the StackElement code-behind isn't handling any events either.

I've tried decoupling the ItemsControl from the CollectionViewSource in favor of binding it directly to the ObservableCollection, which did nothing other than (as I expected) bypass the sorting functionality I added to the ViewSource. I tried handling the events in the StackElement class itself, in addition to making them be tied to other controls contained within StackElement. I tried using DataTriggers, which if I remember worked as expected, but I need to include more advanced logic such as multiselection and the inability to lightly highlight an already-selected StackElement.

For context, I'm intending to use these events to lightly highlight StackElements when the user drags the mouse over them and to strongly highlight them when the mouse is pressed — basically, I need something that looks and feels like Windows File Explorer. From what I've seen this can't be accomplished in an elegant fashion with DataTriggers alone.

Here's my event handlers (in MainWindow.xaml):

```cs
private void StackElement_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp fired for a StackElement.");
}

private void StackElement_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnMouseEnter fired for a StackElement.");
}

private void StackElement_OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnMouseLeave fired for a StackElement.");
}
```

Here's how I'm adding to the bound collection (for testing, which is why it's hooked up to a random button):

```cs
private void Btn_File_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    InitiativeStackElement t = new InitiativeStackElement(new Entity("TestName", 10, 11, 12, 13, null)); //InitiativeStackElement implements INotifyPropertyChanged so the databindings work
    _entityProvider.Elements.Add(t); //_entityProvider is just a reference to a XAML-defined resource class, which is loaded up in the constructor so I don't have to call TryGetResource() whenever I want to use it. it's currently used for testing purposes only
}
```

Finally, here's the portion of my XAML containing the StackElements:

```xml
<Border Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="0,1,0,0" 
        Style="{StaticResource StandardBorder}">
    <ScrollViewer Name="Scv_InitiativeStack">
        <StackPanel Name="Stp_InitiativeStack">
            <ItemsControl Name="Its_InitiativeStack" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedInitiativeStack}}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <con:StackElement Element="{Binding}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="StackElement_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"                                           MouseEnter="StackElement_OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="StackElement_OnMouseLeave"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

The StackElement class just defines a single DependencyProperty of type InitiativeStackElement. The properties of this object are bound to a few controls within the StackElement, which always displays correctly. It's the behavior of the events that have me confused.

As described, I'm expecting the MouseEnter event to fire whenever the mouse is dragged onto the StackElement. However, it's only firing after I fulfill seemingly random conditions that shouldn't affect it's functionality, like mousing over another StackElement first. There are no error messages.

Comment: _"From what I've seen this can't be accomplished in an elegant fashion with DataTriggers alone."_  Why not ?

Comment: Because I've been unable to find examples of DataTriggers being used to implement logic any more advanced than "if A and B, set property".

Comment: As you mentioned you only want to highlight... That can easily be done in XAML

Comment: Well, I don't just want to highlight when the user mouses over something. I also want to highlight (in a different color) when the user clicks on my UserControl. Furthermore, I don't want the lighter mouseover highlight color to appear when the user mouses over an already-selected element. I also intend to add multiselection capabilities, akin to shift-clicking in Windows File Explorer. I couldn't find a way to do all this in XAML alone, so I opted for events.

Comment: I would say all of these are possible and standard functionality. Seems to me that ListView is what you actually need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates

Comment: And if there is more than you need to add to it just make your own control based on ListViewItem:  `class MySpecialListViewItem : ListViewItem`

Comment: Unless you want to set a ListView's View property (to e.g. a GridView), better use its base class, ListBox. It is simpler and should do everything you need. Just put it in the Border element and set its ItemTemplate as you did with the ItemsControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I was able to get the functionality I wanted using ListBox:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="InitiativeStackTemplate">
        <con:StackElement Element="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Border Margin="0,1,0,0" 
        Grid.Row="1"
        Style="{StaticResource StandardBorder}">
    <ScrollViewer Name="Scv_InitiativeStack">
        <ListBox Name="Lbx_InitiativeStack" 
                 SelectionMode="Extended"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedInitiativeStack}}" 
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource InitiativeStackTemplate}"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

Everything works as expected.